# The best model design to save function call into db

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some sort of a `Task`s in my project. Task and its parameters later will be constructed into a function call.

Now my `Task` model looks like:

```
class Task(TimeStampedModel):
    ACTIVE = 1
    COMPLETED = 0
    FAILED = -1
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (ACTIVE, 'Active'),
        (COMPLETED, 'Completed'),
        (FAILED, 'Failed'),
    )
    ACTION1 = 1
    ACTION2 = 2
    ACTION3 = 3
    ACTION_CHOICES = (
        (ACTION1, 'Action1'),
        (ACTION2, 'Action2'),
        (ACTION3, 'Action3'),
    )
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=ACTIVE)
    action = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=ACTION_CHOICES, default=ACTION1)
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Later I will create `Task` object and depending on its `action` call a particular function. For example, if `task.action == 1` I will call `some_module.action1()`. I am curious on how I can store arguments that can be passed to a function (`some_module.action1(arg1, arg2)`) if I am not sure what they will be in the future. So, if it is possible to say so, I want store some sort of a dictionary of function kwargs as my field. What's the best way to archive what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSON field. if you use Postgres, it has built in JSON field support, otherwise you can install(or write by your own ) a library to make pseudo JSON field:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonfield
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

I use django-jsonfield in a few projects and it works smoothly.